# Как работает разрешение пространства имен при вызове дочерней реализации из базового класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Например, есть такой код

```
 struct Iface1
 {
     virtual int f1() = 0;
 };

 struct Iface2 : Iface1
 {
     virtual int f2() = 0;
 };

 class Base2 : public Iface2
 {
 public:
     int f2() override
     {
         int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();  // unresolved symbol
         int r2 = 2 + Base2 ::f1();  // unresolved symbol

         return 3 + f1();  // OK
     }
 };

 class Impl : public Base2
 {
 public:
     int f1() override
     {
         return 13;
     }
 };

 int main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
     auto obj = Impl();
     int a = obj.f2();
     return 0;
 }
```

В функции `Base2::f2` линковщик VS2012 не находит символ `f1` в строках для `r1` и `r2`, а для `return` находит.

Так вот, как именно работает разрешение имен в данном случае, или куда девается диспечеризация времени исполнения?

Comment: Вы написали код, который не имеет смысла. Например, int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();  но класс Iface2 не имеет функции с именем f1.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow правда ваша, исправил код

Comment: Unresolved symbol - это на самом деле ошибка редактора. Вы лучше покажите готовую к компиляции программу, демонстрирующую проблему Имейте в виду, что вы не можете вызывать функцию, если она не определена. У вас все класса абстрактные с неопределенными функциями..

Comment: @VladfromMoscow да нет коментарии я сам добавил естесвенно, ошибки линковщик выдает

Comment: Покажите минимальную, готовую к  компиляции  программу, которая воспроизводит проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вызываете явно два метода класса:

```
int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();  // unresolved symbol
int r2 = 2 + Base2 ::f1();  // unresolved symbol
```

Реализации `f1()` нет ни в `Iface2`, ни `Base2` — поэтому «unresolved symbol». Это пример статического вызова. С другой стороны, мы имеем неквалифицированный вызов `f1`, который откладывается «до лучших времён», т.е. тут происходит динамическая диспетчеризация, которая не даёт ошибки линковщика — разрешение этой ситуации происходит на этапе исполнения, линковщик тут уже роли не играет.

Другими словами: первые два вызова не являются виртуальными, тогда как третий является.

---

Ну и стандарт, собственно:

> *[class.virtual/15]* Explicit qualification with the scope operator
>   (5.1) suppresses the virtual call mechanism

Comment: Вы не внимательно читали мой ответ. Как я написал, если определить функцию f1 в базовом классе Iface1, то она будет вызвана для обоих классов Iface2 и Base2.

Comment: Так что ваш ответ некорректный. По крайней мере не согласуется с результатом, получаемым при запуске программы, если в базовом классе определить функцию f1.

Comment: Я подумал, что возможно, что вы правы. Так как в базовом классе функция не определена, то она не определена и в производных классах.:)

Comment: Вы правы, и я вашему ответу ставлю плюсик.:)

Answer (score 1):

Внутри этой функции

```
 int f2() override
 {
     int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();  // unresolved symbol
     int r2 = 2 + Base2 ::f1();  // unresolved symbol

     return 3 + f1();  // OK
 }
```

вызывается виртуальная функция `f1()`.

При явном указании класса, как, например, `Iface2::f1()` или `Base2 ::f1()` вызываются функции, объявленная в этих классах или наследуемая от базового класса.

Однако в обоих этих классах эта функция, которая наследуется от базового класса `Iface1`, не определена. Не определена она также и в базовом классе Поэтому выдается сообщение об ошибке.

Что касается неквалифицированного вызова `return 3 + f1();`, то так как она определена в классе `Impl`

```
 class Impl : public Base2
 {
 public:
     int f1() override
     {
         return 13;
     }
 };
```

и вызывается для объекта этого класса,

```
 auto obj = Impl();
            ^^^^^^ 
 int a = obj.f2();
```

то включается механизм виртуального вызова и используется таблица виртуальных функций именно этого класса, в которой указатель указывает на определенную в этом классе функцию .

Если бы вы определили эту функцию в классе `Iface1`, как, например,

```
struct Iface1
 {
     virtual int f1() = 0;
 };

int Iface1::f1() { return 1; }
```

то в этих вызовах

```
     int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();  // unresolved symbol
     int r2 = 2 + Base2 ::f1();  // unresolved symbol
```

эта функция бы вызывалась, так как она наследуется данными классами от базового класса. Здесь механизм виртуального вызова не действует.

**Дополнение:** Я решил дополнить свой ответ демонстрационным примером, определив чисто виртуальную функцию `f1` в классе `Iface1`, чтобы показать, что причина состоит в том, что эта функция в исходном примере кода не определена в классе `Iface1`, а потому не может вызываться для объектов производных классов `Iface2` и `Base2`.

Но достаточно определить эту функцию, и программа успешно выполнится.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Iface1
{
    virtual int f1() = 0;
};

int Iface1::f1() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Iface1::f1()" << std::endl; 
    return 1; 
}

struct Iface2 : Iface1
{
    virtual int f2() = 0;
};

class Base2 : public Iface2
{
public:
    int f2() override
    {
        int r1 = 1 + Iface2::f1();
        int r2 = 2 + Base2 ::f1();

        return r1 + r2 + f1();
    }
};

class Impl : public Base2
{
public:
    int f1() override
    {
        std::cout << "Impl::f1()" << std::endl;
        return 13;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Impl obj;
    std::cout << obj.f2() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вы вод программы на консоль будет:

```
Iface1::f1()
Iface1::f1()
Impl::f1()
18
```

Comment: Но `f1` объявлен в `Iface1`, так вот `Iface1::f1` тоже не работает. Кроме того у вас проитовречие выше вы пишете: `Iface2::f1() или Base2 ::f1() вызываются функции, определенные в этих классах`, а в конце: `В таблицах виртуальных функций классов Iface2 и Base2 соответствующие указатели указывают на функцию Iface1::f1, так как в этих двух классах эта функция не была переопределена`. Что мешает использовать эти указатели?

Comment: @Cerbo Функция f1 в классе Base1 не определена. Поэтому так как она также не переопределена в классах Iface2 и Base2, то таблицы виртуальных функций для всех этих трех классов содержат указатель (ноль) на эту неопределенную функцию. В классе Impl функция переопределена, поэтому его таблица виртуальных функций содержит указатель на определение этой функции для этого класса.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать что таблицы другие используются при кфалифицированном вызове. Это нужно в ответе подробнее расписать.

Comment: @Cerbo Я в предыдущем комментарии сделал опечатку. Должно быть " Функция f1 в классе Iface1 не определена. Поэтому.." и т.д.

Comment: @Iface2 Вообще-то, у меня в ответе это отражено.:)

Comment: Извините, но отражено не до конца, вот вы пишите: `используется таблица виртуальных функций именно этого класса` имея в виду `Impl`, но вызов выполняется из `Base2` и как он узнает о таблице `Impl` не понятно

Comment: @Cerbo Функция f2 вызывается для объекта класса Impl., о чем написано в моем ответе. И именно таблица виртуальных функций этого класса используется при вызове функции для объекта этого класса. По-моему все достаточно ясно.

Comment: На мой взгляд, Вы ошибаетесь. Я не вижу ни одной причины, почему при явном вызове(`Iface2::f1()`) может происходить обращение к таблице ВФ. С точки зрения реализации это глупо, да и с точки зрения семантики явный вызов функции должен идти вне рассмотрения таблиц ВФ.

Comment: @ixSci Согласен, я был не прав.:)